# Best way to reload web assemblies without IISReset

Tags: asp.net, iis, iis-6

What's the best way to reload assemblies after you do a publish to a website and or gac some assemblies.

An easy trick I've learned is to touch the web.config and it reloads the app domain.

What are the best practices related to this?

Is it possible to update a Server Activated Serviced Component without an IISRESET that is referenced by a webpage?

Thanks

Answer (score 7, accepted):

you can run

> iisapp.vbs /a "App Pool Name" /r

This will restart the app pool and leave the rest of the app pools untouched. No IIS Services are stopped or started.

Comment: If you can't find your iisapp.vb then just open IIS Management Console and under Application Pools, right click and recycle.

Answer (score 1):

If you do a publish to the website and put new .dll files in the bin, the application will recycle automatically.

If you update the GAC, you will want to either use your save method on the web.config, or simply restart the application pool that the application is in.