# Moving dll from Bin to GAC

Tags: asp.net, gac, bin

What are the issues when we move a dll from BIN folder to GAC?.

1. Is there any modifications required in my config?
2. If application is still running then will it continue using the old dll if no issreset?
3. can I have dll in both places? in Bin & GAC. If so which one will be referered?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Depending on what you want, Web.Config change is optional. You can have DLLs in both places. The Runtime first looks in the GAC and then in the probing path of the application which includes the bin to load an assembly:

[ASP.net assembly loading from GAC or Bin](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/pranav_rastogi/archive/2010/10/18/asp-net-assembly-loading-from-gac-or-bin.aspx)

[Dll in both the bin and the gac, which one gets used?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/981142/dll-in-both-the-bin-and-the-gac-which-one-gets-used)

You can restart the app pool and leave the rest of the app pools untouched. No IIS Services are stopped or started:

[Best way to reload web assemblies without IISReset](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/744990/best-way-to-reload-web-assemblies-without-iisreset)